# Bootstrap 4 navbar flex between?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am just starting out with Bootstrap 4 and trying to use the bootstrap classes mainly instead of using CSS. I have 2 navbars stacked and I want to spread out the nav items like space-between, so that it would take the whole width of the page instead of all stacked towards the left. I messed with d-flex classes and tried some flex-box in the ul. But it's not working.

```css
.text-spLeft{
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.text-spRight{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./header.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">


</head>

<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="nav1">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="./images/dnowlogo.png" class="img-responsive">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
  
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    
                    <div class="line-group">
              
                            <div class="text-right">
                                    <p>Your nearest Location is stfford,tx 77477<span class="text-spLeft"><a href="#">Change</a></span></p>
                                </div>
                        <ul class="navbar-nav  d-flex justify-content-between ">
                                <li class="nav-item ">
                                        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                                            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                            <li class="nav-item ">
                                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Contact Us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item ">
                                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Contact Us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item ">
                                <a class="nav-link " href="#">Contact Us</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                    aria-expanded="false">
                                    United States
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Australia</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Canada</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">India</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>


                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

        <div class="nav2">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <!-- <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button> -->

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav nav justify-content-between">
                        <!-- <li class="nav-item active">
                                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                                </li> -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-expanded="false">
                                Products and Services
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-expanded="false">
                                Solutions
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-expanded="false">
                                Industries
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-expanded="false">
                                About Us
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                aria-expanded="false">
                                Resources Center
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link " href="#">Location</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link " href="#">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>

</html>


<!-- <li class="nav-item ">
        <img src="./images/dnowlogo.png" class="img-responsive">
  </li> -->
```

Comment: Risa is right, `popper.js` needs to go before `bootstrap(.min).js`. You loaded it after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for all flexbox related classes to work (including your `justify-content-{lg-}between`) you need to also add:

- `d-{lg-}flex` and...
- `w-100`

Without the first one, `display` is not `flex` and flex properties do not apply.

Without the second, `justify-content` gets set to `space-between`, but the element doesn't stretch to `100%` so there's no positive space to distribute.

```css
.text-spLeft {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.text-spRight {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./header.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">


</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="nav1">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="./images/dnowlogo.png" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <div class="line-group">
              <p>Your nearest Location is stfford,tx 77477<span class="text-spLeft"><a href="#">Change</a></span></p>
          </div>
          <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
            <li class="nav-item ">
              <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
              </form>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item ">
              <a class="nav-link " href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    United States
                                </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Australia</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Canada</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">India</a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="nav2">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <!-- <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button> -->

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav justify-content-lg-between w-100 d-lg-flex">
          <!-- <li class="nav-item active">
                                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                                </li> -->
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Products and Services
                            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Solutions
                            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Industries
                            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                About Us
                            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Resources Center
                            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link " href="#">Location</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link " href="#">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  </div>


</body>

</html>


<!-- <li class="nav-item ">
        <img src="./images/dnowlogo.png" class="img-responsive">
  </li> -->
```

Note: I also removed the `.line-group` wrapper as it was interfering with the navbar layout.

Answer (score 1):

For starters... You may want to add these two lines **prior** to the bootstrap jquery as stated in their [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/download/) under BootstrapCDN:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

As for your question, it's going to be near impossible to do this without custom CSS from what I can tell after looking through the documentation.

Here's the custom CSS to be able to make the navbar span across the entire page:

```
.navbar-nav{
     width: 100%;
 }
```

Add this within the  tags using  tags.

Comment: You answer does not address the question being asked. Please use comments for improvements outside the scope of the question.

Comment: Added solution.